# How to count the number of equal values in php foreach

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

How to count the number of iterations with the same values in foreach, group the iterations and display with quantities of the same iterations at each group? In other words how to convert foreach with this output result:

```
100
100
100
200
300
300
```

to:

```
100: 3
200: 1
300: 2
```

Comment: What is different? It does exactly what you want?!

Comment: Which answer do you view as the answer to my question? From whom?

Comment: the accepted one, you can use `array_count_values()` to get the amount how many times a certain value is in an array.

Comment: Wasn't a very informative accepted answer.  `foreach(array_count_values($array) as $k => $v) { echo "$k: $v"; }`

Comment: @stckvrw I hope this is note a joke question... Just straight forward: http://viper-7.com/OjZ41D